# I am trying to use kivy on python with Pycharm

Tags: 14.04, apt, python

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE's

I am following the instructions on this website.

I install the linuxbrew and I pass the first and second part.

```
brew install hg sdl sdl2 sdl2_image sdl2_ttf sdl2_mixer gstreamer
```

When I run this code it gives me an error wich is;

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [glfont] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I searched the problem and I encountered with this solution;

```
sudo apt-get install libz-dev or sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev or sudo upt-get install lib32z1-dev
```

none of them worked. It gives me this error when `make ** comment` made out.

Answer (score 0):

If someone will ever encounter with this problem or similar one, I've found the solution. One of the steps doesn't have the necessary package. I manually install this package and my problem was solved. sdl2_ttf